# Trying to get property 'users' of non-object

Tags: php, json

im getting this two errors:
Notice: Trying to get property 'users' of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ig_stats/jsontest.php on line 5

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ig_stats/jsontest.php on line 5

Im trying:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?query=lol'));

foreach($json->users as $item)
{
    if($item->user->username == "lol")
    {
        echo $item->full_name;
    }
}
```

All i want is to get the data in 'full_name' from the 'user' 'lol'.
But i dont know how i can search for it :/

Can someone give me a hint or a solution?

Comment: @Jeff It's an object, he is not passing `TRUE` to the 2nd argument for `json_decode()`.

Comment: yeah, I did a blind shot too quickly...my bad

Comment: What is your PHP version? your code works fine for me (PHP 7)

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error! _BUT_ `$item->full_name` should be `$item->user->full_name`. [See this fiddle](https://3v4l.org/cKJqr) (also for older versions)

Comment: but in the json there are also 'places'. 'hashtags',.. not only users. maybe the error is related but somewhere else?

Comment: @Jeff no it's not because he is only passing the `users` object, OP needs to be more active and reply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: @Mehdi I know. But since the shown code didn't produce the shown error, there was a chance that some relevant code was hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a version where you can't iterate over an object, but if so, you can use the response as an array by passing `TRUE` to `json_decode()` like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?query=lol');
$json = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach($json['users'] as $item)
{
    if($item['user']['username'] == "lol")
    {
        echo $item['user']['full_name'];
    }
}
```

You may want to debug your code, make sure the `$json` contains an object because your code works fine for me, this is what I tried:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?query=lol');
$json = json_decode($json);

foreach($json->users as $item)
{
    if($item->user->username === 'lol'){
        echo $item->user->full_name; // You forgot the user part    
    }
}
```

Both Printed `LOL`.

Comment: Thanks! Both worked fine for me.
I was already on the way of the second one, but didnt finished it correctly :)